# Pre-upload Slides in bigbluebutton

Tags: javascript, node.js, bigbluebutton

how can I Pre-upload Slides with bigbluebutton-js npm package?

```
 let meetingCreateUrl = await api.administration.create(roomName, roomId, {
    attendeePW: attendeepassword,
    moderatorPW: moderatorpassword,
    record:true,
    allowStartStopRecording:false,
    autoStartRecording:true,
    maxParticipants:200,
 
  })
http(meetingCreateUrl)
```

Comment: Looking at the source for bigbluebutton-js it appears to handles api calls as Get requests. Pre-upload Slides  for create only works for Post requests. Creating  api calls  for bbb is pretty easy, Generate the  checksum, configure for the CORs  is most of the work involved.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the slides to your create **POST** request body like this XML:

```
<modules>
   <module name="presentation">
      <document url="http://www.sample-pdf.com/sample.pdf" filename="report.pdf"/>
      <document name="sample-presentation.pdf">JVBERi0xLjQKJ....
        [clipped here]
        ....0CiUlRU9GCg==
      </document>
   </module>
</modules>
```

Just make sure your request is Post and you need to set new configurations for your bigbluebutton server to accept Post requests.

Use these two links for further help:

[Pre-upload Slides](https://docs.bigbluebutton.org/dev/api.html#pre-upload-slides)

[Allow cross-domain requests](https://github.com/mconf/api-mate/tree/master#allow-cross-domain-requests)